# Different Times between View and DisplayForm in Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calendar, date-time

**The setup:**

I am using a default Calendar list in SharePoint 2010 Enterprise. The calendar is being used to track meetings in for a specific meeting room.

The calendar has content approval required and an overlay to show items which are currently pending approval in a different colour. There have been no other modifications to the calendar.

The regional settings are set as English (United Kingdom) with the Time Zone as UTC.

**The Problem:**

We have got a recurring entry in the calendar, set to repeat every Tuesday from 10:00-14:30, but this displays as 10:00 - 13:30 on the calendar view. Is there any setting which would cause the Calendar view and the Display Form to be an hour of sync?

Thanks,